# primefaces selectManycheck box columns attribute is not working

Tags: primefaces

I am using Primefaces 3.5, as shown in showcase, i am trying to use p:selectManyCheckBox.

```
<p:selectManyCheckbox layout="grid"
                      columns="2"
                      value="#{bean.selectedList}">
    <f:selectItems itemLabel="#{bean.value}"
                   itemValue="#{overrides}"
                   value="#{bean.overrideValues}"
                   var="overrides>
</p:selectManyCheckbox>
```

But columns attribute is not working, is there any way to get column wise disply ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I fixed by changing the version of the prime face.

I had 3.2 and changed to 4.0.

For this particular component it seams that it whose added in the last 2 moth.
Requested [here](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=3486) and a specific task [here](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=4549).

---

Is the second time when I also had this kind of problem. I am looking on the prime face showcase website for a specific component and and when I tried that component it didn't work with my version.